# How to convert unix timestamp to Carbon instance in Laravel in model itself?

Tags: laravel

What I have already:

Had this in model:

```
protected $dates = [ 'applied_date' ];
```

In database `applied_date` is stored in this format `2018-05-11 13:31:59`.

so in view I can format it like below:

```
$applied_date->format('m/d/Y')
```

What I want:

In database `applied_date` is already stored in this format `1530205690` (unix timestamp).

I want to format in view like `$applied_date->format('m/d/Y')`, how can I achieve this?

Note: 
We can do `Carbon::createFromTimestamp($applied_date)->format('m/d/Y');`

Comment: Search in the docs about date [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

Comment: Are you saying that when you do `$model->applied_date`, you are not getting a Carbon instance?

Comment: @ChinLeung It sounds like OP would like to store the unix timestamp integer instead of a datetime/timestamp field, so the mutator/accessor approach sounds like the right one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use laravel attributes https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

something like this

```
/**
 * Get formatted applied_date.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateAttribute()
{
    $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($this->applied_date)->format('m/d/Y');

    return $date;
}
```

then in you view you can do this `{{ $model->date }}`